# Limit datalist value - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-datalist

I am trying to render around 2000 values(through an API call) using DataList in AngularJS. The issue is that these values make the page so slow. Is there a way I can render only 10 items at a time and since its a datalist, probably show matching results to a limit of 10 when we type.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyEXMr

```
<main ng-app="myApp">
  <section ng-controller="dataListController">
    <form name="some">
      <label> Search
   <input type="text" list="dataList">
      </label>
      <datalist id="dataList">
        <option ng-repeat="v in names" value="{{v.eyeColor}}">Age {{v.age}}</option>
      </datalist>
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Here's a recipe in the Angular.js docs that may help: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html

Comment: That works. But since I'm getting the whole list of values through an API call, if I try to type in "pink", it doesnt come up when does come up when I remove limitTo filter

Comment: probably - the best idea - limit api and make pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ng-if="$index < 10"` to the option attribute. This will only render the items in with an index less than 10, and will still respect your text filter. LimitTo is returning a new array with only the 10 items in it, causing the text filter to not find your items.

Comment: I used filter and bound it to the model. It works now. In my actual implementation, everything is unique key. Thanks everyone